# Why is this concurrent code slower than the other (both C++)?

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency

I have 2 functions, `test_1` and `test_2` and both should do the same thing at the same speed. But that's not the case with `test_1` being significantly slower. If I run some benchmarks, `test_1` takes around 15x longer than `test_2`. Why is that? And how can I rewrite `test_1` to do the same as `test_2` but with variable number of threads?

```
// The thread which gets called    
void work(std::atomic<int>& a) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        a++;
    }
}

// Aligned atomic int used in both test_1 and test_2
struct alignas(64) AlignedType {
    AlignedType() { val = 0; }
    std::atomic<int> val;
};

// The slow one
void test_1() {
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    threads.reserve(4);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        AlignedType a{};
        threads.emplace_back(work, std::ref(a.val));
    }

    for (auto& thread : threads) {
        thread.join();
    }
}

// The fast one
void test_2() {
    AlignedType a{};
    AlignedType b{};
    AlignedType c{};
    AlignedType d{};

    // Launch the four threads now using our aligned data
    std::thread t1([&]() { work(a.val); });
    std::thread t2([&]() { work(b.val); });
    std::thread t3([&]() { work(c.val); });
    std::thread t4([&]() { work(d.val); });

    // Join the threads
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    t3.join();
    t4.join();
}

int main() {
    test_1();
    test_2();
}
```

Comment: This looks like an obvious cache-line collision to me.

Comment: It looks like there may be a subtle bug in the for loop in `test1`, where the local variable `AlignedType` goes out of scope before the thread is done with it's work. I'm not sure why that would cause things to run slower. Could you try creating a `vector< AlignedType>` in `test1` instead?

Comment: Even without the _undefined behavior_, your test is not a good one. It's too short and `test_1` may have to spin up 4 cores. You _may_ get a different result if you run `test_2` first. How are you measuring? Did you compile with full optimization for speed?

Comment: @mattlangford  how do I do that?

Comment: Check out @NathanOliver's response - it's right on the money

Comment: @TedLyngmo I use Google Benchmark and I'll create more than 4 threads but I had to start somewhere. I plan use the `-O3` flag.

Comment: @topkek Yes, do that. Measuring performance without full optimization is rarely useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your functions are not the same.  `test_1` has undefined behavior, so anything you get from it is suspect.  In the loop

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    AlignedType a{};
    threads.emplace_back(work, std::ref(a.val));
}
```

You pass `a.val` to the thread by reference, but `a` is destroyed at the end of each iteration.  That means all threads have a dangling reference to `val`.  Most likely they are all referring to a single object as the loop is just going to recreate `a` in the same place in each iteration.

To make `test_1` act like `test_2`, you would need a vector of `AlignedType` and you would pass those elements to the thread like

```
void test_1() {
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    threads.reserve(4);
    std::vector<AlignedType> data(4);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        AlignedType a{};
        threads.emplace_back(work, std::ref(data[i].val));
    }

    for (auto& thread : threads) {
        thread.join();
    }
}
```

Comment: This results in a cryptic and long error message for me with the last one being: `/usr/include/c++/10.2.0/thread:136:44: error: static assertion failed: std::thread arguments must be invocable after conversion to rvalues
  136 |           typename decay<_Args>::type...>::value,
      |                                            ^~~~~`

Comment: I think you'd need `std::ref(data[I].val));` instead of just `std::ref(data[I]));`

Comment: @topkek Oops. change `threads.emplace_back(work, std::ref(data[i]));` to `threads.emplace_back(work, std::ref(data[i].val));`